# Computing voltages over resistors

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, homework, ohms-law

[image]

How do you use the combine/redraw method to find the voltages of the different resistors?

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I have no idea how to use the combine/redraw method.  The question is part of a lab that is due today but we haven't even learned how to use the method in lecture yet.

Comment: So yes? What methods have you learned which could be useful to solve this?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. What did you find on combine/redraw through internet searches? This should be well documented there. I'm afraid the site can't be for personal tutorial on subjects already documented and freely available.

Comment: To find the voltage at point a to ground you don't need to do any calculation at all.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework so I won't give specific answers but the "combine and redraw" method means that you add resistances together in series or parallel until you get to a point where you can calculate currents.  You then use those currents to calculate node voltages (or use the voltage divider equation, which is a specific application of the same), use those voltages to find branch currents, and keep going until you get the specific current or voltage you want.

Answer (score -1):

I can see that R3 and R4 are in series, so these can be replaced by a single resistor (R3+R4).

Now we have R2 in parallel with (R3+R4).  So we can calculate (R2||(R3+R4)).

We now have R1 and (R2||(R3+R4)) forming a voltage divider for voltage a (which is 12V), so we can calculate voltage b.

Then un-combine R3 and R4.  This is now a voltage divider on voltage b, so we can calculate voltage c.

Given voltages a, b, c and ground (which is 0V by definition), we can calculate the voltage across each resistor.